# Buscar palabras seguidas en listas Python

Tags: python

Este es mi codigo:

```
import re 

scripts = [
    ["La banana es redonda", "El cangrejo es azul", "El cielo esta verde"],
    ["El techo es lava", "El invierno se acerca", "Cuidado Morty"],
    ["La primera con el nombre", "La madre de dragones", "Soy un pepinillo Morty"],
    ["Me siento supercalifragilisticoespialidoso", "Cual camino tomar", "No se a donde ir"],
    ["Si no sabes a donde vas entonces toma cualquier camino", "El rey en el norte", "El que no puede ser nombrado"],
]

find_script = False

for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    text = "Soy un pepinillo Morty"
    text_lower = str.lower(text)
    text_split = text_lower.split()

    for p in sublist:
        p_lower = p.lower()
        p_final = re.sub('[!@#$?.,]', '', p_lower)
        p_split = p_final.split()

        #print(text_split)
        #print(p_split)

        if any(word in text_split for word in p_split):
            print(f"FOUND {index}")
            find_script = True


if find_script == False:
    print("No found")
```

Lo que hace es buscar si coincide cualquier palabra de text_split conp_split. Mi problema es que no quiero que sea una sola palabra, quiero tener un limite. Porque en el ejemplo que coloque coinciden con 2 listas, la 1 y la 2, porque ambas tiene la palabra "Morty".

En otras palbras:
Quiero que coincida la oracion de la lista con mayor palabras en "text".

Comment: ¿Las coincidencias tienen que ser de palabras **estrictamente seguidas**?

Comment: ¿Qué sugieres? Creo que es lo ideal, pero, estoy abierto a otras soluciones, obviamente hay varios caminos.

Comment: Porque puedes simplemente buscar coincidencias de palabras dentro de las oraciones.

Comment: Es posible, pero, ¿cómo sería? Porque como te digo, lo que tengo ahora solo busca coincidencias exactas.

Comment: No sé si por _coincidir_ te refieres a evaluar la [_distancia entre coincidencias_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distancia_de_Levenshtein), pero puedes echarle un visazo a [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy). Aquí un [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python).

Comment: ¿Quizás una expresión regular te serviría? Todo depende de lo que necesites realmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es la respuesta ideal al problema que tienes, pero ya la había hecho sin percatarme de que necesitabas coincidencias de **palabras contiguas**. Te sugiero una función que busque la cantidad de veces que las palabras de una oración se repiten en otra:

```
def cantidadCoincidencias(objetivo,oracion):
    coincidencias = 0
    palabras = objetivo.split(" ")
    for palabra in palabras:
        if(oracion.find(palabra)>=0):
            coincidencias +=1
            print(f"Coincidencia con palabra: {palabra}")
    print(f"Se encontraron {coincidencias} coincidencias de la palabra: '{objetivo}' en la oración: '{oracion}'")
    return coincidencias
        
        
cantidadCoincidencias("manzana roja", "en el lago hay una manzana")
cantidadCoincidencias("manzana roja", "en el lago hay una manzana roja ")
cantidadCoincidencias("manzana roja", "en el lago hay una banana azul")
```

Resultado:

```
Coincidencia con palabra: manzana
Se encontraron 1 coincidencias de la palabra: 'manzana roja' en la oración: 'en el lago hay una manzana'
Coincidencia con palabra: manzana
Coincidencia con palabra: roja
Se encontraron 2 coincidencias de la palabra: 'manzana roja' en la oración: 'en el lago hay una manzana roja '
Se encontraron 0 coincidencias de la palabra: 'manzana roja' en la oración: 'en el lago hay una banana azul'
```

Lo que se hace es que se divide la `string` original en palabras separadas por medio del operador `split()` y luego se hace un recorrido del `array` resultante para comparar cada palabra con la oración original por medio del método `find()`.

Lo dejo acá esperando que te sea de ayuda ¡Suerte programando!

### UPDATE

```
scripts = [
    ["La banana es redonda", "El cangrejo es azul", "El cielo esta verde"],
    ["El techo es lava", "El invierno se acerca", "Cuidado Morty"],
    ["La primera con el nombre", "La madre de dragones", "Soy un pepinillo Morty"],
    ["Me siento supercalifragilisticoespialidoso", "Cual camino tomar", "No se a donde ir"],
    ["Si no sabes a donde vas entonces toma cualquier camino", "El rey en el norte", "El que no puede ser nombrado"],
]

def cantidadCoincidencias(objetivo,oracion):
    coincidencias = 0
    palabras = objetivo.split(" ")
    for palabra in palabras:
        if(oracion.find(palabra)>=0):
            coincidencias +=1
    return coincidencias
    
find_script = False
cantidad_congruencias = 1
mayor_congruencia_actual= 0
match =""
target= "I'm un pepinillo, Morty"

for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    for  ele in sublist:
        congruencias = cantidadCoincidencias(target,ele)
        if(congruencias>=cantidad_congruencias):
            find_script = True
            if(congruencias >= mayor_congruencia_actual):
                match = ele
            print(f'\nExisten {congruencias} congruencias entre:\n\tLa frase:"{target}"\n\tY la sublista #{index}, elemento: "{ele}"')
    
print(f'\nCongruencia mayor:{match}')
    
if find_script == False:
    print("No found")
```

Con la variable `cantidad_congruencias` puedes definir cuántas congruencias ocupas como mínimo entre tu frase y la string de la sublista para determinar si ha encontrado un match.

Comment: Pense en el split, pero, el problema es que puede coincidir con otras busco que el resultado sea solo 1, quizas el que tenga palabras que mas coincidan.

Comment: Puedes usar esta función para escoger el elemento de tu array que tenga el mayor número de coincidencias. O escoger que si tiene cierto número de coincidencias, entonces que sea un "Found". Por ejemplo, si tiene 2 coincidencias o 3.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que colocaste un fomato diferente, no pusiste una lista con sublitas, se puede hacer con listas?

Comment: Creí que era algo trivial... Ya que en tú código haces el recorrido de la sublista. Voy a editarlo.

Comment: Como le hago para que solo muestre la oracion con la mayor {congruencias}, porque muestra todas?

Comment: Puedes llevar una cantidad máxima de congruencias y si se excede esté numro entonces guardas las string que genera este numero de congruencias. Muestra todo porque quería que entiendieras que sucede con el código. Te actualizo la respuesta...

Comment: Mil gracias, Fran.

Comment: Tengo otra pregunta, ¿como hago que la congruencia mayor sea mayor siempre y cuando tenga un número mayor? Porque ahora si las congruencias son iguales me da cualquier número, en vez de un False, ando intentado hacerlo.

Comment: Ahora entendi lo que dijiste de la variable cantidad_congruencias, el problema esta en que las coincidencias pueden ser 1 si es una palabra o pueden ser 20 si es una oracion larga, no lo se, eso depende del largo de la oracion. Hay alguna forma de hacer que tome la coincidencia mayor unicamente?

Comment: Puedes hacer que solo cuente la primera ocurrencia, entonces tendrías un incremento en tu cuenta por cada palabra de la oración de pruebas... Algo cómo que si escribes `Hola Morty` y la sublista es `Morty, Morty, Morty`, te arroje `1` en vez de `3`; contando ocurrencias únicas. La otra es que agarres la cantidad de ocurrencias y lo dividas entre el largo de la oración... Así tomas en cuenta el largo, eso es lo que se me ocurre así rápidamente.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste, coloque varias condicionales. por ejemplo, si la oracion tiene 4 palabras coloque dos condicionales para que muestre las oraciones con congruencias 3 y 4. Pero, mi problema es que las muestra todas, no la que mas congruencias tiene, porque itera la lista (recorre una por una, y muestra la lista en orden). Puedes ayudarme con mi problema? Porque como te digo, mi objetivo es que si no hay 4 congruencias al menos se tenga la posibilidad de 3 congruencias, no todas.

Comment: En vez de *if(oracion.find(palabra)>=0):* coloque un *if oracion.find(palabra) >= int(len(objetivo.split())):* y veo que solo sale la que coincide, es decir, la solucion de mi problema (a medias), pero, aqui entre nos, no se lo que hice exactamente (tengo una idea0, me explicas, por favor? (ando aprendiendo).